# About the notation on a musical score (Баха Сюита номер 2)

Tags: перевод, музыка, сокращения

In the violoncello score of Баха Сюита номер 2 (Bach's Cello Suite No. 2 in D minor, BWV 1008), there are two abbreviated instructions that I don't understand, can someone explain what they mean?

One says:

> до С.С.

and later there's another:

> В.П.

Also, I want to know where to find a musical dictionary for Russian terminology, since there are a lot of scores with Russian instructions in them.

---

Here's an image of the score:

[image: Sheet music of Bach's Cello Suite No. 2 in D minor, BWV 1008. The instructions "до С.С." appears part way through the 31st measure, (the last measure of the first page). The instruction "В.П." appears at the start of the second page.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"До С.С." is "до середины смычка" (up to the middle of the bow), "В.П." is "верхняя половина" (upper half [of the bow]).

Source: http://otvet.mail.ru/question/173565791

Comment: Спасибо большое! and also thank you for taking the time to ask this somewhere else! :]

Comment: @Nikolay Ershov, I took some time trying to resolve this - unsuccessfully. I take my hat off. :)

Comment: Great answer! In English, this is MB, but the abbreviation commonly used is "A.C.D.A." This abbreviation stands for "Al Centro Dell'Arco" and is often seen in violin sheet music to indicate playing at or up to the middle of the bow. I'm a violinist :)